# Diferenciar Resultados con numeraciones Iguales SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo una vista de SQL Generada, a la cual llamo luego por un Sistema de Gestión, mi intención es juntar 3 bases de datos que son idénticas pero cada una representa a una empresa y así poder unificar datos.

---

Ahora bien mi **problema** radica en que cuando el sql ejecuta mi vista, este confunde numeraciones de pedidos generados y los suma a pedidos con la misma numeración pero de otra empresa (BASE) generando información falsa.

Ejemplo

`Tengo el pedido Nº 00010000617 del talonario 8o`

`Tengo el pedido Nº 00010000617 del talonario 95`

Lo que esperaba que hiciera la vista era mostrar esos pedidos separados por el talonario, pero en su lugar, los Suma ignorando uno de los dos, es decir o agrega todo al **80** o al **95**.

**Este es el código SQL:**

```
 SELECT *

  GVA21.TALON_PED AS [Desc. talonario], 
  GVA21.NRO_PEDIDO AS [Nro Pedido], 
  GVA14.RAZON_SOCI AS [Razon social], 
  CASE WHEN GVA03.COD_ARTICU = ' ' THEN NULL ELSE GVA03.COD_ARTICU END AS [Cod. 
  Articulo], 
  GVA03.PRECIO AS [Precio], 
  GVA03.CANT_PEDID AS [Cantidad Pedida], 
  GVA21.COD_CLIENT AS [Nro Cliente],  
  GVA21.ESTADO WHEN 1 THEN 'INGRESADO' WHEN 2 THEN 'APROBADO' WHEN 3 THEN 
  'CUMPLIDO' WHEN 4 THEN 'CERRADO' WHEN 5 THEN 'ANULADO' WHEN 6 THEN 'REVISADO' 
  WHEN 7 THEN 'DESAPROBADO' ELSE '' END AS [Estado],
  SUM (CASE 'BIMONCTE' WHEN 'BIMONCTE' THEN (CASE GVA10.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN 
  GVA03.PRECIO ELSE (GVA03.PRECIO * GVA21.COTIZ) END) * (1 - (GVA03.DESCUENTO) / 
  100) * (GVA03.CANT_PEDID) * ( 1 - GVA21.PORC_DESC/100 ) WHEN 'BIORIGEN' THEN 
  (CASE GVA10.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN (GVA03.PRECIO / GVA21.COTIZ) ELSE GVA03.PRECIO  
  END) * ((1 - (GVA03.DESCUENTO) / 100)) * (GVA03.CANT_PEDID) * ( 1 - 
  GVA21.PORC_DESC/100) WHEN 'BICOTIZ'  THEN (CASE GVA10.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN 
  (GVA03.PRECIO)  / CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 1 END ELSE (GVA03.PRECIO) * 
  GVA21.COTIZ  /  CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 1 END END) * ((1 - 
  (GVA03.DESCUENTO) / 100)) * (GVA03.CANT_PEDID) * ( 1 - GVA21.PORC_DESC/100) 
  END) AS [Total sin Impuestos],
  SUM   (GVA03.CANT_PEDID * (CASE WHEN GVA21.N_LISTA = 4 THEN GVA03.PRECIO * 
  GVA21.COTIZ ELSE GVA03.PRECIO * 1.21 END)) AS 'TOTAL',
  GVA21.LEYENDA_1 AS [Leyenda],
  CASE GVA21.ESTADO WHEN 1 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 2 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 3 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 4 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 5 THEN 'FELIPE SA' ELSE '' END AS [Empresa],
CASE WHEN GVA21.FECHA_PEDI = '01/01/1800' THEN NULL ELSE GVA21.FECHA_PEDI END AS [Fecha Pedido] 


FROM dbo.GVA21 
LEFT JOIN GVA14 ON GVA14.COD_CLIENT = GVA21.COD_CLIENT
LEFT JOIN GVA03 ON GVA03.NRO_PEDIDO = GVA21.NRO_PEDIDO
LEFT JOIN GVA10 ON GVA10.NRO_DE_LIS = GVA21.N_LISTA

GROUP BY GVA03.COD_ARTICU, GVA21.NRO_PEDIDO, GVA21.TALON_PED, GVA21.ESTADO, GVA21.COD_CLIENT, GVA14.RAZON_SOCI, GVA21.ESTADO, GVA21.FECHA_PEDI, GVA21.FECHA_ENTR, GVA03.CANT_PEN_D, GVA10.MON_CTE, GVA03.PRECIO, 
GVA21.LEYENDA_1, GVA03.CANT_PEDID, GVA03.CANT_PEN_F, GVA21.FECHA_PEDI*
```

---

Probé agruparlo de diferentes formas, agregar las columnas de sus respectivos ID para tratar de separarlos, pero siempre me termina dando el mismo resultado.

Son mis primeros pasos en SQL así que seguramente sea algún error en la sintaxis o algún mal uso de los Joins pero la verdad es que no se donde esta el problema.

Comment: Lo que esta mal es el group by. La forma de agrupacion esta dado por el orden de los campos en el group by. Si tu primer columna es cod_articulo, entonces primero agrupa por ese campo. No se cual de los montones de campos necesitas ni el orden pero tu problema esta ahi.

Comment: Y como recomendación, si son tus primeros pasos, para construir consultas complejas, se va agregando de a un campo y da a una tabla y se verifican los resultados parciales.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo del todo claro la pregunta, pero entiendo que quieres una "PK" con el pedido y el talonario, así que yo probaria a concatenarlos y hacer el order by sobre el campo concatenado

```
 SELECT 
  GVA21.TALON_PED AS [Desc. talonario], 
  GVA21.NRO_PEDIDO AS [Nro Pedido], 
  GVA14.RAZON_SOCI AS [Razon social], 
  CASE WHEN GVA03.COD_ARTICU = ' ' THEN NULL ELSE GVA03.COD_ARTICU END AS [Cod. 
  Articulo], 
  GVA03.PRECIO AS [Precio], 
  GVA03.CANT_PEDID AS [Cantidad Pedida], 
  GVA21.COD_CLIENT AS [Nro Cliente],  
  GVA21.ESTADO WHEN 1 THEN 'INGRESADO' WHEN 2 THEN 'APROBADO' WHEN 3 THEN 
  'CUMPLIDO' WHEN 4 THEN 'CERRADO' WHEN 5 THEN 'ANULADO' WHEN 6 THEN 'REVISADO' 
  WHEN 7 THEN 'DESAPROBADO' ELSE '' END AS [Estado],
  SUM (CASE 'BIMONCTE' WHEN 'BIMONCTE' THEN (CASE GVA10.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN 
  GVA03.PRECIO ELSE (GVA03.PRECIO * GVA21.COTIZ) END) * (1 - (GVA03.DESCUENTO) / 
  100) * (GVA03.CANT_PEDID) * ( 1 - GVA21.PORC_DESC/100 ) WHEN 'BIORIGEN' THEN 
  (CASE GVA10.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN (GVA03.PRECIO / GVA21.COTIZ) ELSE GVA03.PRECIO  
  END) * ((1 - (GVA03.DESCUENTO) / 100)) * (GVA03.CANT_PEDID) * ( 1 - 
  GVA21.PORC_DESC/100) WHEN 'BICOTIZ'  THEN (CASE GVA10.MON_CTE WHEN 1 THEN 
  (GVA03.PRECIO)  / CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 1 END ELSE (GVA03.PRECIO) * 
  GVA21.COTIZ  /  CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 1 END END) * ((1 - 
  (GVA03.DESCUENTO) / 100)) * (GVA03.CANT_PEDID) * ( 1 - GVA21.PORC_DESC/100) 
  END) AS [Total sin Impuestos],
  SUM   (GVA03.CANT_PEDID * (CASE WHEN GVA21.N_LISTA = 4 THEN GVA03.PRECIO * 
  GVA21.COTIZ ELSE GVA03.PRECIO * 1.21 END)) AS 'TOTAL',
  GVA21.LEYENDA_1 AS [Leyenda],
  CASE GVA21.ESTADO WHEN 1 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 2 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 3 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 4 THEN 'FELIPE SA' WHEN 5 THEN 'FELIPE SA' ELSE '' END AS [Empresa],
CASE WHEN GVA21.FECHA_PEDI = '01/01/1800' THEN NULL ELSE GVA21.FECHA_PEDI END AS [Fecha Pedido] 


FROM dbo.GVA21 
LEFT JOIN GVA14 ON GVA14.COD_CLIENT = GVA21.COD_CLIENT
LEFT JOIN GVA03 ON GVA03.NRO_PEDIDO = GVA21.NRO_PEDIDO
LEFT JOIN GVA10 ON GVA10.NRO_DE_LIS = GVA21.N_LISTA

GROUP BY GVA03.COD_ARTICU, **GVA21.NRO_PEDIDO+GVA21.TALON_PED**, GVA21.ESTADO, GVA21.COD_CLIENT, GVA14.RAZON_SOCI, GVA21.ESTADO, GVA21.FECHA_PEDI, GVA21.FECHA_ENTR, GVA03.CANT_PEN_D, GVA10.MON_CTE, GVA03.PRECIO, 
GVA21.LEYENDA_1, GVA03.CANT_PEDID, GVA03.CANT_PEN_F, GVA21.FECHA_PEDI*
```